# Is there any way to reload a page with a button click in next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am currently working on a next.js project and i should somehow reload my page in order to make a new API request. I am new to it so i do not know how to do it. I tried some methods but they did not worked. Here is my code it is an app that tells gives you random destination points.

```
import React from 'react';
import useSWR from "swr";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const Profile = function Profile() {
  
  function GetData(){
    const {data,error} = useSWR("https://miras-backend.herokuapp.com/random");
    return {data,error}
  }
  const {data,error} = GetData();
  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
  return (
  
    
    <Card>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
          Eserin Adı      
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
          {data.title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography  color="textSecondary">
          {data.adress}
          <br/>
          <br/>
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
          {data.about}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button onClick={()=> {Profile()}}>Sonraki</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: You probably don't need to "somehow reload my page in order to make a new API request", almost sure that there is a way to make a new request without reloading the page. Please describe your problem with more information

Comment: Like Vencovsky said you should find a way to reload only the api request instead of reloading the entire page. Anyway the easy way to reload is to call window.reload() on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your approach is not correct, you can do this

```js
const Profile = function Profile() {
  
   const {data, error, mutate} = useSWR("https://miras-backend.herokuapp.com/random");
  
  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
  return (
    
    <Card>
      <CardContent>
         .....
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button onClick={()=> {mutate(); /* <-- this will trigger a reload */}}>Sonraki</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

> **Update**
> `swr` expose also a `revalidate` method that is the canonical way to refresh cache.

```js
const Profile = function Profile() {
  
   const {data, error, mutate, revalidate} = useSWR("https://miras-backend.herokuapp.com/random");
  
  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
  return (
    
    <Card>
      <CardContent>
         .....
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button onClick={()=> {revalidate(); /* <-- this will trigger a reload */}}>Sonraki</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - let currentLocation = window.origin;   // get url of current page
 - window.location.href = currentLocation // redirect
```